# How to read data from csv file and save to database and also many to many relationship in spring boot

Tags: csv, spring-boot

I really need help.

I want to read data from csv file in my Spring Boot project, and then I want to save to database using @Transactional.

How ever, I have 2 classes.

One is Role:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long roleID;

    private String role;

    @ManyToMany( mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

    private Role(){} //


    public Long getRoleID() {
        return roleID;
    }

    public void setRoleID(Long roleID) {
        this.roleID = roleID;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

}
```

And other one is User:

```
@Entity
@Table( name="users" )
public class User {


    public User(){

    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userID")
    private Long userID;



    //  @NotNull(message = "Username text are must not be empty !")
    private String userUsername;


   // @NotNull(message = "Name text are must not be empty !")
    private String userName;
    //  @NotNull(message = "Surname text are must not be empty !")
    private String userSurname;

    //  @NotNull(message = "Please choose a password")
    private String password;

    //  @NotNull(message = "Please choose a password")
    @Transient
    private String passwordMatch;

    // @NotNull(message = "Give adress please")
    private String addres;
    // @Email(message = "Please enter valid e mail.")

    private String eMail;

    private boolean active = false;

    private String key;



    @ManyToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="userID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="roleID")}
    )
```

I want to read from csv file and than save to database both user and role entities. How data will be ? I cant figure out in my mind.

Also How can I read data using library or on my own program?

Also one more thing If one data is broken at User I should not save data to database both User and Role. I think it can be implemented with @Transactional?

Any ideas? I really need help. Thanks for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need reading and writing to a CSV file, you can use the [Jackson-datafomrats](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv) library

Find an [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-app-setup-with-csv-files)

Or if you need a transactional one you can use [spring batch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use FlatFileItemReader to read file or use Apache POI with ItemReader. While to Write JPAItemWriter or JDBCItemWriter for given entities.